# Ionic 3: Ignoring 'back' swipes inside a given div

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an Ionic 3 app which contains a Leaflet map. This map works great, except for when the user pans westward by swiping from the left side of the screen, which triggers a 'back' navigation.

Is there a way to ignore 'back' swipes from inside a certain div in Ionic 3? I'd rather not use `ionViewCanLeave()` since I want the user to be able to swipe back from other parts of the view.

Comment: Have you tried to setup `swipe` handler (see the docs [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#Gestures)) for your leaflet map and do nothing/prevent the event's default in the handler?

Comment: I tried `(swipe)="$event.preventDefault(); $event.stopPropagation()"` but that doesn't do anything.